# How to get find an ActionSheet using Xamarin UITest?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I am currently trying to write an Android UITest in my Xamarin.Forms application, but I am unsure how I am supposed to interact with an ActionSheet that is being shown. Note that by ActionSheet I mean the pop-up that is shown when calling `DisplayActionSheet(string title, string cancel, string destruction, params string[] buttons)`.

Unlike with views, I cannot simply add an AutomationId to the ActionSheet as it is not defined in my SearchForExercisesPage (see screenshot) and therefore I suppose that I cannot simply use something like:

`app.Tap(foo => foo.Marked("ActionSheet").Index(1))`

Have anyone tried using Xamarin UITest to interact with an ActionSheet?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D34T6.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.Tap(foo => foo.Marked("Exercise Details"));
```

Or this:

```
app.Tap(foo => foo.id("text1").Text("Exercise Details"));
```

Or this:

```
app.Tap(foo => foo.id("text1").Index(1));
```